# Как сделать три блока слева по центру и справа в css?

Tags: html, css, html5

У меня есть вывод на страницу:

```
<html lang="en">

<meta charset="utf-8">
<div class="cneter_top">
<div class='content_center_news'>
<a href=https://site.com/test/news/alternative-mining-algorithms-reap-higher-profits-than-bitcoin-mining-2021><h1>Alternative Mining Algorithms Reap Higher Profits Than Bitcoin Mining in 2021<img src=https://site.com/images/minerssaa.jpg alt="site.com"></h1></a>
</div>
</div>
<div class='content_left_news'>
<a href=https://site.com/test/news/localbitcoins-adds-bitcoin-cash-other-cryptocurrencies-payment-methods><h6>Localbitcoins Adds Bitcoin Cash and Other Cryptocurrencies as Payment Methods<img src=https://site.com/images/shutterstock_1132053830.jpg alt="site.com"></h6></a>
<a href=https://site.com/test/news/south-koreas-financial-regulator-holds-closed-door-meeting-20-crypto-exchanges><h6>South Korea’s Financial Regulator Holds Closed-Door Meeting With 20 Crypto Exchanges<img src=https://site.com/images/skmeeting.jpg alt="site.com"></h6></a>
</div>
<div class='content_right_news'>
    <a href=https://site.com/test/news/amundi-executive-pascal-blanque-calls-cryptocurrencies-a-farce><h6>Amundi Executive Pascal Blanque Calls Cryptocurrencies a Farce<img src=https://site.com/images/shutterstock_1941524785.jpg alt="site.com">2021-06-10 15:45:08</h6></a>
    <a href=https://site.com/test/news/aquagoat-saving-the-oceans-one-ecocoin-at-a-time><h6>AquaGoat: Saving the Oceans One EcoCoin at a Time</h6></a>
<a href=https://site.com/test/news/philippine-mobile-wallet-gcash-buy-sell-cryptocurrencies><h6>Popular Philippine Mobile Wallet Gcash Explores Letting Users Buy, Sell, Store Cryptocurrencies</h6></a>
<a href=https://site.com/test/news/norton-crypto-mining-antivirus-software-mine-cryptocurrency><h6>Norton Crypto Mining: Antivirus Software to Mine Cryptocurrency</h6></a>
</div></html>
```

Как мне оформить в css в таком формате ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/BaWqYjp - вот так можно - хотя и на flexbox тоже можно

Comment: Спасибо мне это помогло